# Product shippable and/or downloadable. What's the best option?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product, grouped-products, downloadable

## The problem:

I have to sell **products which are downloadable but they can be shippable as well as CD or USB Key**. Thus, customer can choose if download the product or receive it on DVD or USB Key.

### What's the best option to handle this situation in Magento 2?

---

#### What I did:

Till now, using Magento 1, I was selling the product in just 2 options: downloadable or shippable on CD. In order to do this I created 3 products: *1 simple product (for CD)*, *1 downloadable product (for download)*, and *1 grouped product (to group those 2 products)*. However, this is very inconvenient because every time I have to insert a new product I have to insert 3 separated products and now that I want to give the USB key option, *I should insert 4 separated products*.

I tried to use a configurable product in order to create them but since I'm using a custom Attribute Set with many required fields, the child products created from this process inherit the parent Attribute Set and they force me to compile all those fields. I also tried to change it once the child products have been created but I got I mess...

#### What I was thinking:

I was thinking about alternatives... something like creating just 1 downloadable product for every products and then creating just 1 simple product for CD shipping and another for USB Key shipping for all products so the customer who wants shipping buys 2 products: the downloadable product and the simple product for CD shipping for example. But, in my opinion, this is not an elegante way to handle this situation.

Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a configurable product with a custom product attribute which is a drop down with 3 values. Virtual, CD and USB. You can add additional costs to the 2 simple products to cover the shipping or you can write a custom module or rule to give free shipping for the virtual option and normal shipping options for the other 2.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think doing like that the customer isn't able to receive the email with the download link. It seems a little bit a mess but could avoid to manage many products (which is what I could like achieve). Another problem could be the checkout process which could wrongly ask for shipping or not.

Answer (score 0):

Historically , shipping include "package" as a box and manage, in your case this shall included as "write on cd or usb drive and send product to" all included  in shipping price, thus help to manage right inventary.

Comment: Aditionally you shall think in transfer to cloud storages like to google drive, dropbox etc.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point. What about downloadable products?

Comment: a downloadable product is  a "digital information" like to software, music , image , etc to transfer to client that buy it. this not need a shipping, magento has already this type of product , because in starndard shipping it "drop this steep"